# Progress bar Android studio

Tags: android

I want my android studio progress bar to start my second activity when it's done loading , but it seems that I can't get it to work no matter what code people give me or no matter how i change things up . It's always the same result . Nothing happens. It just loads and when it reaches the max it does nothing and I want it to start the second activity . I tried multiple strategies but nothing happens . So i'm hoping somebody can help me with the problem .

MainActivity :

```
package com.example.brandon.territories;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private ProgressBar progressBar;
private int progressStatus = 0;
private ImageView ImageView;
private Handler handler = new Handler();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);

    //Long operation by thread
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            while (progressStatus < 100) {
                progressStatus += 4;
                //Update progress bar with completion of operation
                handler.post(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        progressBar.setProgress(progressStatus);
                    }
                });
                try {
                    // Sleep for 300 milliseconds.
                    //Just to display the progress slowly
                    Thread.sleep(300);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }).start();
}

class MyProgressBar extends ProgressBar
{
    public MyProgressBar(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    @Override
    public void setProgress(int progress)
    {
        super.setProgress(progress);
        if(progress == this.getMax())
        {
            //Do stuff when progress is max
            Intent intent  = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items
    //to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
}

}
```

content_main:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:src="@drawable/logo2"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="53dp" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="Loading..."
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<ProgressBar
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/progressBar"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:max="100"
    android:progress="0"
    android:indeterminate="false" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

SecondActivity :

```
package com.example.brandon.territories;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;


public class SecondActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);

}

}
```

Comment: What's the value returned by `getMax()`?

Comment: Are you sure the execution is reaching `Intent intent  = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);`?

Comment: @DigitalNinja It looks like it . I don't know if it does for sure because i'm new to android studio

Comment: Okay, put a `Log.d("max progress");` in there before `Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);` and see if it shows up in your logcat.

Comment: I'm getting a red line under it @DigitalNinja

Comment: Sorry, you have to include android.util.Log at the top of your file - `import  android.util.Log;`

Comment: @DigitalNinja i get a red line under this (100) and when i put ("max progress") i still get a red line .

Comment: I'm not sure what is happening, anyway I suspect that piece of code is not getting executed and that's why your second activity is not started. Take a look at http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log.html, it can really help when trying to find problems in the future. In the meantime one of the answers below will probably solve your problem.

Comment: @ChaseWIlliams I see you're still having trouble. I just realized I told you wrong and that's why you were having trouble using the log output. It should be `Log.d("progressbar debug", "reached max progress");` (or whatever text you want), It takes a label and a message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could change your `MyProgressBar` class to this :

```
class MyProgressBar extends ProgressBar{
Context mContext;
public MyProgressBar(Context context) {
    super(context);
    this.mContext = context;
}

@Override
public void setProgress(int progress)
{
    super.setProgress(progress);
    if(progress == this.getMax())
    {
        //Do stuff when progress is max
        Intent intent  = new Intent(mContext, SecondActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

### EDIT

Also you are using a `ProgressBar` but not your `MyProgressBar` so if you want to use your `ProgressBar` declare it as :

```
MyProgressBar progressbar = new MyProgressBar(getActivity());
```

### EDIT2

Change your `MainActivity` to this and it will work.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private ProgressBar progressBar;
private MyProgressBar pb;
private int progressStatus = 0;
private ImageView ImageView;
private Handler handler = new Handler();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    pb = new MyProgressBar(this);

    //Long operation by thread
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            while (progressStatus < 100) {
                progressStatus += 4;
                //Update progress bar with completion of operation
                handler.post(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        progressBar.setProgress(progressStatus);
                        pb.setProgress(progressStatus);
                    }
                });
                try {
                    // Sleep for 300 milliseconds.
                    //Just to display the progress slowly
                    Thread.sleep(300);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }).start();
}

class MyProgressBar extends ProgressBar
{
    public MyProgressBar(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    @Override
    public void setProgress(int progress)
    {
        super.setProgress(progress);
        if(progress == this.getMax())
        {
            //Do stuff when progress is max
            Intent intent  = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items
    //to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Where do i put that ? Because it's still not working.

Comment: Put what? @ChaseWIlliams

Comment: MyProgressBar progressbar = new MyProgressBar(getActivity());

Comment: Replace it with `private ProgressBar progressBar;` otherwise you can test my edit2 (the xml code)

Comment: I don't see any private ProgressBar progressBar; In my main activity file

Comment: In EDIT 2, code is running two ProgressBars in parallel :/

Answer (score 0):

In xml use:

```
<com.example.brandon.territories.MyProgressBar
style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/progressBar"
android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
android:max="100"
android:progress="0"
android:indeterminate="false" />
```

instead of:

```
<ProgressBar
style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/progressBar"
android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
android:max="100"
android:progress="0"
android:indeterminate="false" />
```

Also it will be necessary to have class MyProgressBar in its own java file just like Activites.

Answer (score 0):

The code in `MyProgressBar` is never running because you are declaring a `ProgressBar` in your layout. Either change the layout to use your extended class or change your `Runnable` to something like this:

```
public void run() {
    while (progressStatus < 100) {
        progressStatus += 4;
        //Update progress bar with completion of operation
        handler.post(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                progressBar.setProgress(progressStatus);
            }
        });
        try {
            // Sleep for 300 milliseconds.
            //Just to display the progress slowly
            Thread.sleep(300);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    handler.post(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            Intent intent  = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });     
}
```

Comment: Now the progress isn't moving

Comment: Something else must be going on then as I only added the last 6 lines to your existing code and nothing there should have broken your code to update the `ProgressBar`. Check out @DigitalNinja's link and start tossing log statements in the code to figure out what is executing and what is not.

Answer (score 0):

This is working for me. Logic is to increment the status 1 by 1 and show it in the screen as loading

public class StartPage extends AppCompatActivity
{

```
private ProgressBar progressBar;
private int progressStatus = 0;
private Handler pHandler = new Handler();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_start_page);

    progressBar = findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);

    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            while (progressStatus < 100) {
                progressStatus++;
                android.os.SystemClock.sleep(20);
                pHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        progressBar.setProgress(progressStatus);
                    }
                });
            }

            if(progressStatus == 100)
            {
                Intent intent = new Intent(StartPage.this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        }
    }).start();
}
```

}

This is the xml code for progress bar. android:progressDrawable="@drawable/progressbar" this is for change the progress bar color. I create xml file in drawable folder.

```
<android.support.v4.widget.ContentLoadingProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="2dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:indeterminate="false"
    android:max="100"
    android:progress="0"
    android:progressDrawable="@drawable/progressbar"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.885" />
```

This xml file is for change the color in progress bar.

```
<item android:id="@+id/progress">
    <clip>
    <shape>
        <gradient android:startColor="@color/textColor"
            android:centerColor="@color/textColor"
            android:endColor="@color/textColor"
            android:gradientRadius="20dp"
            >
        </gradient>
    </shape>
    </clip>
</item>
```